# Can I define "document" as a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In my application, I sometimes want to define "document" for use in querySelector as "tinymce.get('steps_html').contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0].contentWindow.document". Other times, I want "document" to have it's usual meaning.

Is there a way I can set "document" to be a variable? I've tried the following, none of which return an element:

Defining document:

```
document = tinymce.get('steps_html').contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0].contentWindow.document;
document.querySelector(myElement)  // Returns nothing
```

Defining a prefix:

```
prefix = tinymce.get('steps_html').contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0].contentWindow;
prefix.document.querySelector(myElement);  //Returns nothing
```

Defining a prefix as text:

```
prefix = "tinymce.get('steps_html').contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0].contentWindow;
    prefix.document.querySelector(myElement)";  //Returns nothing
```

Only `tinymce.get('steps_html').contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0].contentWindow.document.querySelector(myElement)` returns an element.

Comment: Using same name for different use cases would be confusing.

Comment: I am guessing this is the snag: `tinymce.get('steps_html')` Maybe not storable as a static value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. I'll post it in case anyone else comes across this post.

First, find your TinyMCE Editor iframe

```
var iframe = document.querySelector("#myDiv .tox-editor-container .tox-edit-area iframe");
```

Then get its contents

```
var iframe_content = iframe.contentDocument;
```

Then you can perform your queries

```
var frame_li = iframe_content.querySelectorAll("#tinymce li");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
window.orig_document = window.document
window.document = tinymce.get('steps_html').contentAreaContainer.childNodes[0].contentWindow.document
window.document = window.document.orig_document

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Just paste that whole line before I call window.document.querySelector(myElement)? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: well I was suggesting to put window before document.  You would have to store the original to get it back...